# Rest Api design, connecting two resources

Tags: api, rest

Let's say I have a resource Order and a resource Product. Internally Product has a primary key based on its name so cannot be two product with the same name. What is the correct way in rest api to associate a product to a specific order?

1. POST orders/{orderId}/products , BODY {name:glasses} -> in this case I give the name of product so internally the api need to retrieve it from db to see if already exists instead of trying to create the product and after it associate it with the order in the db, right?

is this way correct or somehow should I search before the id of the product and with a rest endpoint pass it to associate to the order?